# How to plot a line that is partially colorized?

Tags: matplotlib

As shown in the figure,
How can I plot a line that have different colors based on a specific value of x ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution here may be to slice your data at the corresponding index of `x_lim` found by [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) :

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,100)
y = np.cos(x)*np.exp(-x/2)

# specify your x limitation
x_lim = np.pi
# find the first corresponding idx where the condition x>=x_lim hold
x_lim_idx = np.where(x>=x_lim)[0][0]

# plot sliced data
plt.plot(x[:x_lim_idx],y[:x_lim_idx],'r')
plt.plot(x[x_lim_idx:],y[x_lim_idx:],'b')
```

which gives for `x_lim = np.pi` :

[image: output_sliced]

And if the remaining gap between the lines bothers you, for small `x` discretization for instance, you can still close it by making the two slices overlap.

Comment: Probably ` np.where(x>=x_lim` is a bit more accurate.